# RNN outputs NaN after weight update

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm implementing an auto encoder setup where both the encoder and decoders are Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs). The encoder and decoder model is initialized like so:

```py
def enc(message, weights, biases):
    message = tf.unstack(message, 4, 1)
    fw_cell = rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden_enc)
    with tf.variable_scope("encoder"):
        outputs, _ = rnn.static_rnn(fw_cell, message, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases

def dec(codeword, weights, biases, time_steps):
    codeword = tf.expand_dims(codeword, axis=2)
    codeword = tf.unstack(codeword, 7, 1)
    fw_cell = rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden_dec)
    with tf.variable_scope("decoder"):
        outputs, _ = rnn.static_rnn(fw_cell, codeword, dtype=tf.float32)
    a = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases
    weight_fc = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.01, size=[4, 4])
    init = tf.constant_initializer(weight_fc)
    return tf.layers.dense(a, units=4, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, kernel_initializer=init)
```

And I am using a `mean square error` loss function along with `Adam` optimizer.

```py
# message_hat is the output of the decoder neural network, input_bits is the input to the encoder network
loss = tf.reduce_sum(0.5 * (tf.squeeze(input_bits) - message_hat) ** 2) / float(batch_size)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

---

When I print the output of the decoder network at the end of epoch 0, I get some floating point values, but as soon as I run one more epoch, all the values default to `NaN`. This is true for both encoder and decoder. So I tried gradient clipping using the following code:

```py
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
gvs = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in gvs]
train_op = opt.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
```

Still having the same problem. More precisely, this is the output from epoch 1 onwards:

```
Epoch: 1
Decoding loss: nan
Decoder output: [[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]]
```

Is there something inherently wrong with the code? Suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.